# Updating an UI upon changes

Tags: android, user-interface

I am building an app that displays a bunch of information that the user can edit, and I am having trouble keeping the UI updating the data displayed so it is consistent with the new edits done at runtime.

I have implemented updateUI methods that basically look like:

```
void updateUI(){
    ((TextView) fieldDisplay).setText(fieldCurrentValue);
    ...
}
```

I know I can run this method in things like an AsyncTask or similar stuff that makes it execute continuously. But I'm concerned about efficiency since its not really necessary to update the UI all the time, but only when the user inputs a value which is not that often.

What would be the best approach to this?

EDIT:
The question is how to make sure the an UI element shows the current value of a field, regardless of how or why that field is updated.

My case specifically is the with this. I'm trying to make an RPG character sheet, and I have like a bazillion Skills, which are affected by another lot of fields, such as Characteristics, Modifiers, Categories...

The application should behave so, whenever any of the many fields affects it changes, it should display the new value.
Now, since keeping track of what field affects what is part of the problem, if could update whenever any field whatsoever changes, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Why don't you use a Listener?

Comment: Why don't you call the updateUI function inside the editing function?

Comment: What do you mean  by " when the user inputs a value"? What does trigger updateUI method? Is it a save button? Or a TextChangedListener from an edittext? We need a bit more of contextualization here to help you out.

Comment: Your question lacks in information, what the user input is(Edittexts etc?), what views you are updating?, are the update required only for one screen? You don't need to use AsynTask. After user input event dispatches you can update the related views you want to update.